# java sftp, can't upload file >20K

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

It's a weird issue, with winscp from windows desktop, or unix command, can upload any file to the SFTP server.

But a java class using jsch, from both windows and unix, can't upload files >20K, to that SFTP server. After a while the file will be created in remote folder but only get 16K, then the java eventually got time out, and the remote file stay as 16K.

Any one can heap on this?

Thanks

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: have you looked through the api to see if there are any limits or any options that need to be set to upload a greater then 20k file?

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer [File Transfer using Java JSch - SFTP](http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-uploading-file-to-sftp-server/)

Comment: Nothing special on my code, just take from sample code.

Comment: if there is a limits on server, how come I can use winscp and unix command without problem